# Typeset references without newlines between entries

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reduce bibliography to one line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/reduce-bibliography-to-one-line)

Is it possible to typeset references without inserting a new line between items, i.e. to make the references section look something like:

> Foo et al. 2008, Nature, 100, 200 •
>   Bar & Baz et al. 2010, Science, 300,
>   400 • Einstein, 1905, New Scientist,
>   5, 6

where "•" is perhaps some configurable delimiter character, rather than something like:

> Foo et al. 2008, Nature, 100, 200
>
> Bar & Baz et al. 2010, Science, 300, 400
>
> Einstein, 1905, New Scientist, 5, 6

I use BibTeX at the moment to get something like the second example, and would prefer to continue to use it for the time being if possible, so solutions that don't involve migration to biblatex are particularly welcome!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/reduce-bibliography-to-one-line) question. The accepted answer does not use biblatex. ;-)

Comment: Since "reverse tagging" is rather unusual, I removed the `[biblatex]` tag.

Comment: despite your reluctance to switch to biblatex, you should look at answers to this question: [What to do to switch to biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/215)

Comment: Sorry, I realise this probably isn't the right place, but I'm struggling with the accepted answer to [that](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/reduce-bibliography-to-one-line) question. The "Add Comment" link is missing, presumably because I lack the reputation. Is there a particular place I could seek clarification on this? I have a minimal non-working example.