# Reduce natbib bibliography to one line

Tags: bibliographies, paragraphs, natbib

I would like my references to look like

> Foo et al. 2008, Nature, 100, 200 •
>   Bar & Baz et al. 2010, Science, 300,
>   400 • Einstein, 1905, New Scientist,
>   5, 6

where "•" is perhaps some configurable delimiter character, rather than like:

> Foo et al. 2008, Nature, 100, 200
>
> Bar & Baz et al. 2010, Science, 300, 400
>
> Einstein, 1905, New Scientist, 5, 6

One (the crucial?) difference between my question and a [similar previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11854/typeset-references-without-newlines-between-entries) is that I use natbib and author-year citations. Here's a minimal example, that uses [Stefan's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/reduce-bibliography-to-one-line/5574#5574), but has a couple of problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{paralist}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
  \section*{\refname}%
  \let\par\relax\let\newblock\relax%
  \inparaenum[{\textbullet}]}{\endinparaenum}
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{\item}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Author,
    Author = {{Author}, A.},
    Journal = {Science},
    Month = dec,
    Pages = {493-+},
    Title = {{Title A}},
    Volume = 490,
    Year = 1922,
    }

@article{Buthor,
    Author = {{Buthor}, B.},
    Journal = {Nature},
    Month = nov,
    Pages = {748-+},
    Title = {{Title B}},
    Volume = 136,
    Year = 1962,
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Citations: \cite{Author,Buthor}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

The problems are: (1) The citations in the text are question marks (I get errors like `` Package natbib Warning: Citation `Author' on page 1 undefined on input line 37.) `` and (2) I'm redefining the list environment to put a bullet every time, which feels wrong semantically, and results in `Package paralist Warning: Incorrect label; no or multiple counters.`

The third (and I think separate) problem is to do with my BiBTeX style file, [`mn.bst`](http://ads.harvard.edu/pubs/bibtex/astronat/mnras/mn.bst). If I use that rather than, e.g. `plain`, not only are the citations questions marks, but the references are screwed up and look like

> • Author(1922)]Author Author A., 1922, Science, 490, 493 • Buthor(1962)]Buthor Buthor B., 1962, Nature, 136, 748

Note the citations and references look fine if I comment out the material between `\usepackage{paralist}` and `\usepackage{filecontents}`.

Guidance on any or all of these problems would be very welcome, and guidance that postpones my inevitable migration to biblatex especially so! :-)

Comment: I was looking to do this a couple of years ago and solicited both `natbib` and `biblatex` solutions on comp.text.tex.  No one volunteered a `natbib` solution, but there is a very simple `biblatex` solution.  The question then is how particular is the `mn.bst` style that it couldn't quickly be replicated using `biblatex`.  Alternatively (assuming that you only want this for a short list of refs. you could do it semi-manually using  `\bibentry` commands from `natbib`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing the `\renewcommand{\bibitem}[1]{\item}` seems to work.

EDIT: try this....

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{paralist}
\let\olditem\item
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
  \section*{\refname}
  \let\par\relax\let\newblock\relax
  \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{\olditem[\textbullet]}%
  \inparaenum}{\endinparaenum}

\begin{document}
Citations: \cite{Author,Buthor}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{mn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That fixes the missing citations and the garbled references with mn.bst, but the delimiter (\textbullet in this case) disappears.

Comment: @Mike Right. The `natbib` `\bibitem` command is quite complicated, so exchanging it with something like just `\item` as in the original suggestion simply doesn't work.

Comment: @Mike, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think I must have used this question as the template for my work... but this package: https://github.com/keflavich/tex_compact_bib implements exactly the above, while also limiting the bibliography to 3 authors before going to 'et al'.