# References (bibliography) to one line

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, bibitem

I would like to list references in a single line continuously without line breaks.
There is a good example of doing this: [Reduce natbib bibliography to one line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11903/reduce-natbib-bibliography-to-one-line/11964#11964?newreg=fdbe6f7aa3e34b0f96e683eb53186d3e)

In the above link, I tried Lev Bishop's answer and it worked very well.
But in this answer, I would like to change the bullets to just numbering (e.g., if I have three references, then "[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUlTc.png)...; [2]...; [3]..."). So, I played some time with the `\olditem[\textbullet]` part. But, I couldn't find the solution.

How can I use the auto-numbering (e.g., [item number]) in this code, instead of the bullet?

**EDIT**

Here I give a short example of my latex code of the issue.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={blue}} 
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{paralist}

\let\olditem\item
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
  \section*{3~~~References}
  \let\par\relax\let\newblock\relax
%  \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{\olditem[\textbullet]}%
  \inparaenum}{\endinparaenum}

\textheight=247mm
\textwidth=180mm
\topmargin=-7mm
\oddsidemargin=-10mm
\evensidemargin=-10mm
\parindent 10pt
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%% Start of document %%%%% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%================================================================================
\section{Good day}

Hello.

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[abcde et al.(2999)]{abcde}
abcde, z., et al. 2999, GGG, 123, 4;

...
...(this is just a short description, so all references are omitted)
...

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Thanks to frabjous's suggestion, now all references start with [number] automatically. But, I have two more questions. As you can see the capture image (resultant reference section produced by the above example) below,

[Q1] There are unwanted empty spaces between references. How can I remove them?

[Q2] Is there a way to give a color only to the heading numbers in the Reference section?
For example, (1)...; (2)... --> colored (1)...; colored (2)...

[image: The numbering works, but ugly empty spaces appeared]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Are the citations themselves numeric? If so, then you should use `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` and you could probably just remove the line `\renewcommand{\item}[1][]{\olditem[\textbullet]}` from Lev Bishop's answer and use the default definition of `\item`. If they're author-year, then add in something like `\newcounter{bibitem}\setcounter{bibitem}{0}\renewcommand{\item}[1][]{\refstepcounter{bibitem}\olditem[{[\thebibitem]}]}`? Not sure exactly what you're looking for. If these suggestions don't help, post a minimal working example.

Comment: You have tagged your question with many tags. Some of the packages/methods mentioned in the tags are incompatible with each other. (Specifically `biblatex` is incompatible with `natbib` and `\bibitem`.) From the linked question it looks like you are looking for a BibTeX/`\bibitem`/`natbib`-based answer, but it would really help if you could edit your question to clarify that.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I just removed ```biblatex``` from the textbody. I also tested frabjous's answer and it worked, thanks! But as you can see this edited version, I have two more questions. Do you happen to know how to solve them?

Comment: @frabjous Hi, I edited the text. Do you happen to know how to solve the above mentioned questions? Thanks.

Comment: @sadradio Not sure. It would help to know what documentclass you're using. For the color, do you just want [1], [2], etc. colored in the References, or do you mean the citations, or both, or ... ?

Comment: @frabjous Thank you for replying! The class is `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}`. The latter is only those heading numbers: [1], [2] in the Reference section.

Comment: I think you can get rid of the gaps by adding `\let\hfil\relax` after `\let\par\relax\let\newblock\relax` and can add color with, e.g.,  `\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\RenewDocumentCommand{\bibitem}{om}{{\color{blue}\oldbibitem[#1]{#2}}}`. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up what I wrote in the comments, to return the list labels to numbers, use `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` and remove the line `\renewcommand{\item}[1][]{\olditem[\textbullet]}` line from Lev Bishop's answer in the linked answer.

To remove the gaps between the list items, add `\let\hfil\relax` to `\let\par\relax\let\newblock\relax` in that answer.

To color the labels, you could do, for example, `\let\oldbibitem\bibitem \RenewDocumentCommand{\bibitem}{om}{{\color{blue}\oldbibitem[#1]{#2}}}`; change the color to whatever you want, and load the `xcolor` package with one of its options to add to the possible color names. (See [its documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor?lang=en).)

So all in all, we have something like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue},urlcolor={blue}} 
\usepackage{textgreek}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{paralist}

\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
  \section*{3~~~References}
  \let\par\relax\let\newblock\relax\let\hfil\relax
  \inparaenum}{\endinparaenum}

\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\RenewDocumentCommand{\bibitem}{om}{{\color{blue}\oldbibitem[#1]{#2}}}

\textheight=247mm
\textwidth=180mm
\topmargin=-7mm
\oddsidemargin=-10mm
\evensidemargin=-10mm
\parindent 10pt
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%% Start of document %%%%% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%================================================================================
\section{Good day}

Hello.

\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[abcde et al.(2999)]{abcde}
abcde, z., et al. 2999, GGG, 123, 4;

...

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer is perfect!