# BibLaTeX bibliography without square brackets

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

My current BibLaTeX bibliography output looks like this:

[1] Bob et al. “How to Make Cheese”. In: Farming 101 (2010). [2] Cohen. “The Varities of Cheeese" In: International Journal of Cheese (2003). [3] Cox et al. “Cheese: A Comparative Guide”. In: Cheese Aficionados (2002).

(The single line bibliography was achieved using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8071/7478).)

I would like the bibliography to look like this:

**1.** Bob et al. “How to Make Cheese”. In: Farming 101 (2010). **2.** Cohen. “The Varities of Cheeese" In: International Journal of Cheese (2003). **3.** Cox et al. “Cheese: A Comparative Guide”. In: Cheese Aficionados (2002).

But I am not sure how to bold the numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See also [Removing brackets from biblatex references for lncs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171567/35864)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using the exact content from the answer you linked to:

Change the `defbibenvironment` code to this:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {}
  {}
  {\addspace
   {%
     \printfield{prefixnumber}%
     \textbf{\printfield{labelnumber}}.}%
   \addhighpenspace}
```

I've removed `\printtext[labelnumberwidth]` to remove the brackets and wrapped the `\printfield{labelnumber}` with a bold command (and added in the period). With this .bib file:

```
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}

@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}

@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
```

This output is produced for the bibliography:

[image: References]

Comment: Basically, you are my hero right now.