# Removing brackets from biblatex references for lncs

Tags: biblatex

I want [BibLaTeX bibliography without square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142916/biblatex-bibliography-without-square-brackets), but without putting things all on one line, because that's what lncs requires.

That is, I have

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}

@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}

@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And I want the same bibliography (multiple lines), just without the square brackets.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You just need this one line

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbold{#1\adddot}}
```

to print the label in bold without brackets followed by a dot.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbold{#1\adddot}}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{cicero,baez/article,baez/online,wilde}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is certainly the best way to go. +1.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \textbf{\printfield{labelnumber}}\addperiod}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \textbf{\printfield{labelnumber}}\addperiod}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}

@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}

@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

BTW: I've changed `\bibliography` to `\addbibresource` since the former is deprecated with `biblatex`.