# Use parentheses for citation numbers with BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex

For a scientific paper using the BibLaTeX package, I am requested to format the citation numbers as following:

- When citing references, use superscript numbers and half-width closing parentheses ")" in the right corner of the text to indicate: "this method was investigated<sup>1)</sup> in the past";
- When printing references in bibliography, use numbers and half-width parentheses: "(1) Author, etc."

Given an arbitrary style, how can I achieve this?

Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

This method was investigated\cite{key} in the past.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the publisher not give you a mandatory LaTeX template that takes care of that?

Comment: No, only a MS Word document.

Comment: Maybe you have a look at this (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407) so that you can improve your question.

Comment: I added a MWE as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Citing reference

The answer depends on what citation command we are using.

BibLaTeX provides the command `\supercite` for superscript citations, that we can redefine (from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60923/100137)):

```latex
\DeclareCiteCommand{\supercite}[\mkbibsuperscript]
{\iffieldundef{prenote}
  {}
  {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
  {}
  {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \usebibmacro{cite})}
{\supercitedelim}
{}
```

It is possible to replace other citation commands (e.g. `\parencite`).

`\textcite` is more complicated, we have to redefine this macro (from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162316/100137)):

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
  {\usebibmacro{cite}}
  {%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
    {\bibclosebracket\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
    {}%
    \iffirstcitekey
    {}
    {\textcitedelim}%
    \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
    {\printnames{labelname}}%
    \addspace
    \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {}%
    \mkbibsuperscript{\usebibmacro{cite})}%
    \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
    \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
\makeatother
```

One can improve this solution by adding a space between consecutive citations:

```latex
\renewcommand{\supercitedelim}{, }
```

However, this solution uses BibLaTeX macros that are defined by the bibliography style itself (e.g. `\usebibmacro{cite}`), which is `numeric` here. It may not work with other styles without adaptation.

###### Printing reference

Inspired from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171735/100137).
We simply change a field format:

```latex
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{(#1)}
```

The result for the MWE, with replacing `\cite` by `\supercite`:

[image]