# biblatex - change appearance of reference number as they appear in the References section only

Tags: biblatex

I would like to change the appearance of the References section such that:

- the labels appear like `1.`  instead of `[1]`
- the labels are hanging left into the margin, and the text is aligned with the margin instead of the numbers

I would like to keep the reference appearance as `[1]` as it appears in the main body of my text.

Looking through the `biblatex` manual, this doesn't seem obvious.

Comment: Maybe have a look at my question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633984). This may give you an idea of how to provide an MWE for this kind of question.

Comment: Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171716

Answer (score 1):

You want to set `leftmargin` to zero in the bibliography environment. Take the [default from `numeric.bbx` (ll. 24-37)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/24a94f8f608872e11d259d7c581fc90ea76542a5/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx#L24-L37) and play around with the values until you like the outcome.

The number formatting in the bibliography can be modified by playing with the [`labelnumberwidth` field format](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/24a94f8f608872e11d259d7c581fc90ea76542a5/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx#L21).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\addperiod}
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}

\lipsum[1-2]

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Numbers formatted and aligned as described.]

Answer (score 0):

Using `enumitem` package, I did the following:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}%
{\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0pt,labelsep=2ex,itemsep=2pt]}%
{\end{enumerate}}%
{\item}%
```

Comment: This is really not a great way to do it because you're relying on the labels to coincidentally match. That's much more liable to break.

Comment: What is the better approach? 3.8.7 of the manual provides an example not much different than this. Is better to explicitly show ` \printfield{labelnumber}`? 

https://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf

Comment: moewe's is a better approach. Defining a suitable field format and using the label is better.