# condense non-numbered bibliography into one line

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking, paralist

What I am trying to do is basically the same as (almost) answered here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5574/39336

The difference is that I am using a different `bibstyle`. This `bibstyle` creates the `thebibliography` that I copied into this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0cm}

\begin{document}

Let us cite \citet{Author:1976} \citep[but also][]{Someone:2000}.

\begin{thebibliography}{93}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi

\bibitem[{Author {et~al.}(1976)Author, Other, \&
  Yetanother}]{Author:1976}
Author, F., Other, S., \& Yetanother, T. 1976, Obscure Journal, 25, 314

\bibitem[{Someone {et~al.}(2000)Someone, Someother, \& Thirdone}]{Someone:2000}
Someone, F., Someother, S., \& Thirdone, T. 2000, Otherjournal, 321, 42
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

This gives a bibliography like

> Author, F., Other, S., & Yetanother, T. 1976, Obscure Journal, 25, 314
>   Someone, F.,   Someother, S., & Thirdone, T. 2000, Otherjournal, 321, 42

But I'd like to get a bullet-separated list without line breaks (probably using `paralist` package, similar to the enumerated list from the link above) like:

> Author, F., Other, S., & Yetanother, T. 1976, Obscure Journal, 25, 314 • Someone, F.,   Someother, S., & Thirdone, T. 2000, Otherjournal, 321, 42

while still having the hyperlinks working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with the environment `inparaitem` from `paralist`.

Add the following lines to your preamble.

```
\usepackage{paralist}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{\let\par\relax%
  \section*{\refname}\inparaitem}{\endinparaitem}
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}{\item[\textbullet]\oldbibitem}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0cm}

\usepackage{paralist}
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{\let\par\relax%
  \section*{\refname}\inparaitem}{\endinparaitem}
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}{\item[\textbullet]\oldbibitem}

\begin{document}

Let us cite \citet{Author:1976} \citep[but also][]{Someone:2000}.

\begin{thebibliography}{93}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi

\bibitem[{Author {et~al.}(1976)Author, Other, \&
  Yetanother}]{Author:1976}
Author, F., Other, S., \& Yetanother, T. 1976, Obscure Journal, 25, 314

\bibitem[{Someone {et~al.}(2000)Someone, Someother, \& Thirdone}]{Someone:2000}
Someone, F., Someother, S., \& Thirdone, T. 2000, Otherjournal, 321, 42
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Of course the hyper references don't work anymore...

Comment: Great - thanks! Any chance to get rid of the first bullet? The bullet should be a separator between entries and only appear between two items