# how to get rid of first bullet in paralist-bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, counters, paralist

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165000/condense-non-numbered-bibliography-into-one-line), I managed to get a single-paragraph-bibliography using `paralist`. Now I want to get rid of the first bullet. I got it working for a normal `paraenum` list, but it fails for the bibliography. How can I manage this?

Here is an example: removing the bullet works, but not in the bibliography:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0cm}

% ========== DEFINE COUNTER DEPENDENT BULLET ============
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mybullet}{%
    \ifnum\value{enumi}=1
    \else
        \textbullet
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{paralist}

% ====== REDEFINE BIBLIOGRAPHY ===================
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{\let\par\relax%
  \section*{\refname}\inparaenum}{\endinparaenum}
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}{\item[\mybullet] \oldbibitem}

\begin{document}

% ====== IT WORKS IN PARALIST =========
Test paralist without first bullet:
\begin{inparaenum}[\mybullet]
\item bullet-free first item
\item second item
\item third item
\end{inparaenum}

% ====== BUT NOT IN THE BIBLIOGRAPHY =========
Let us cite \citet{Author:1976} \citep[but also][]{Someone:2000}.

% ========== BIBLIOGRAPHY ============
\begin{thebibliography}{93}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi

\bibitem[{Author {et~al.}(1976)Author, Other, \&
  Yetanother}]{Author:1976}
Author, F., Other, S., \& Yetanother, T. 1976, Obscure Journal, 25, 314

\bibitem[{Someone {et~al.}(2000)Someone, Someother, \& Thirdone}]{Someone:2000}
Someone, F., Someother, S., \& Thirdone, T. 2000, Otherjournal, 321, 42
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Also if someone manages to fix hyperlinks from the citation to the bibliography (not necessarily to the specific item), that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help

```
% ====== REDEFINE BIBLIOGRAPHY ===================
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{\let\par\relax%
  \section*{\refname}\inparaenum[\mybullet]}{\endinparaenum}
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}{\item \oldbibitem}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}
\setlength{\bibsep}{0.0cm}

% ========== DEFINE COUNTER DEPENDENT BULLET ============
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mybullet}{%
    \ifnum\value{enumi}=1
    \else
        \textbullet
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{paralist}

% ====== REDEFINE BIBLIOGRAPHY ===================
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{\let\par\relax%
  \section*{\refname}\inparaenum[\mybullet]}{\endinparaenum}
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}{\item \oldbibitem}

\begin{document}

% ====== IT WORKS IN PARALIST =========
Test paralist without first bullet:
\begin{inparaenum}[\mybullet]
\item bullet-free first item
\item second item
\item third item
\end{inparaenum}

% ====== BUT NOT IN THE BIBLIOGRAPHY =========
Let us cite \citet{Author:1976} \citep[but also][]{Someone:2000}.

% ========== BIBLIOGRAPHY ============
\begin{thebibliography}{93}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi

\bibitem[{Author {et~al.}(1976)Author, Other, \&
  Yetanother}]{Author:1976}
Author, F., Other, S., \& Yetanother, T. 1976, Obscure Journal, 25, 314

\bibitem[{Someone {et~al.}(2000)Someone, Someother, \& Thirdone}]{Someone:2000}
Someone, F., Someother, S., \& Thirdone, T. 2000, Otherjournal, 321, 42
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course no hyperlinks...