# How to make citations in one line with bibtex custom bst?

Tags: bibtex

Right now, my bibtex citations look like

```
[1] Book Title
[2] Book Title
[3] Book Title
```

I want them to be like

```
[1] Book Title [2] Book title [3] Book title.
```

I have a bst file that I am using with a document class file. It's a really huge file so I made a gist (https://gist.github.com/pomegranate1/8ff97eff81dcf310f9ed); I think the relevant portion of code occurs around line 1350, but I'm not sure. I tried removing the lines that say $newline, but end up breaking the whole thing. Could someone please advise me how to do this? It's for a grant I'm writing. I know that others have asked similar questions before, but I wasn't able to get their solutions to work either.

Thanks

Comment: Hi! I don't think that this depends on your bibliography style, since it's the `\bibitem` macro that takes care of this, and it is defined in the LaTeX2e kernel.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what that means exactly. Is there a way I could modify this, or override it to get the functionality I want? Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165000/condense-non-numbered-bibliography-into-one-line, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/reduce-bibliography-to-one-line. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) if you want specific help with code. (Or wait for somebody prepared to trawl through thousands of lines but you might end up waiting a long time.)

Comment: Your terminology is a bit confusing: Are you looking to change the format of the citation callouts in the text or of the bib entries in the References/Bibliography section?

Comment: I'd like to change the format in the bib entries in the references section.