# Reduce biblatex to one line

Tags: biblatex

I am using the `biblatex` package in an article document, and am trying to list references all in one line, as the writer of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/reduce-bibliography-to-one-line?noredirect=1&lq=1) is trying to do. I've tried the fix that is offered, but it didn't work as expected since I am using `biblatex`. I tried to follow the link in the second answer that mentions `biblatex`, but the link is broken. In his answer, he mentions a parameter called `\defbiblatex`, but I could not find its definition in the biblatex documentation.

Currently, I am using `biblatex` as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric-comp,
sort=nty
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bbl}

\renewcommand{\refname}{References \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}} % no extra vert. space after title
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0pt} % no extra vert. space between bib items

\printbibliography
```

What is the simplest way for me to format the bibliography so that the resultant citation list will look like:

> [1] Article 1 [2] Article 2 [3] Article 3 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8071/35864) to [Reduce bibliography to one line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5571/35864) contains a fully compilable example document that shows exactly what you could do. There is no need to follow any links to understand the main point of the answer (indeed link rot is one of the main reasons why self-contained answers are encouraged here).

The command you are looking for is called `\defbibenvironment`. The standard settings in a `numeric` style look like this

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

The idea in lockstep's answer is to remove the list environment from that definition and have everything printed as normal text in the same line.

There is just one tiny detail in lockstep's answer that I'd change: It was written for an older version of `biblatex` where the `labelprefix` field was still called `prefixnumber`. With a current version of `biblatex` I'd suggest

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric-comp,
  sorting=nty,
]{biblatex}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {}
  {}
  {\addspace
   \printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
     \printfield{labelprefix}%
     \printfield{labelnumber}}%
   \addhighpenspace}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography without forced line breaks.]

---

Note that the option to specify the sorting is called `sorting` and not `sort`.